# Specify test case not to run in parallel with TestNG runner in Spring using Cucumber

Tags: java, spring, automation, cucumber, testng

I've been able to configure the project to run test cases in parallel using a TestNG runner; however, there are a handful of scenarios that are not very thread safe.  If these test cases were to run in parallel, they'd interfere with each other.  Now there are a couple of ways I could make these scenarios thread safe, but I was wondering if there was a way to specify these Cucumber scenarios not to run in parallel.

Is there a specific tag I could configure to tag scenarios not to run in parallel?  Specify certain feature files not to run in parallel?  I believe I might have come across something like that for JUnit 5, but does this exist with TestNG?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike JUnit 5, TestNG does not provide such fine-grained controls. At best you can create multiple runner classes with a different selection of features and different configurations for parallel/serial execution.

Comment: Yes actually I didn't think of having multiple runners; cool idea.  That way I can tag whatever tests I want to run by themselves and specify them in their own runner.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I just realized was I could make the number of threads an argument; with a default of 1 thread.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                            <value>1</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <includes>
                        <include>api.automation.tests.runners.TestNGRunnerTest</include>
                    </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have one Jenkins build that has all the tests tagged with the same name to run in parallel with however many threads needed.

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="${CucumberFilterTag} and not @opentofix" -Dspring.profiles.active=${Environment} -Ddataproviderthreadcount=4
```

And in the other build, I have a very similar command (with a different tag) just without the added arguement; to use the default of just one thread.  This will run all those tagged tests one at a time.

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="${CucumberFilterTag} and not @opentofix" -Dspring.profiles.active=${Environment}
```

Either way, the first answer still works, but just thought to add this possibility.